# In C# change a property to read-only at run-time

Tags: c#, .net

I'm making an attribute class that takes a generic. This generic would be a class the user creates that sort of mimics the appSettings section in the config file. They make a property for each key and this attribute lets them map that key to that field. When they instantiate my class using their class as the generic I go through their class looking for my attribute and when found I use the name they set to find that appSetting key and then set that properties value to that appSetting value while also converting it to whatever type they set their properties.

So basically this is a mapping attribute that strongly types the appSettings in the config file. It makes it so the mapping is done in a class instead of the user having to do it inline in their code and cluttering it up. Nice and clean mapping.

**My last step is that I want to mark their properties as read-only, but I can't figure out how to do that as the CanWrite property of the PropertyInfo class is itself read-only.**

```
/// <summary>
    /// This class will fill in the fields of the type passed in from the config file because it's looking for annotations on the type
    /// </summary>
    public class StrongConfiguration<T> where T: class
    {
        // this is read only
        public T AppSettings { get; private set; }

        public StrongConfiguration()
        {
            AppSettings = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));

            // find properties in this type that have the ConfigAttribute attribute on them
            var props = from p in AppSettings.GetType().GetProperties()
                        let attr = p.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ConfigAttribute), true)
                        where attr.Length == 1
                        select new { Property = p, Attribute = attr.First() as ConfigAttribute };

            // find the config setting from the ConfigAttribute value on each property and set it's value casting to the propeties type
            foreach (var p in props)
            {
                var appSettingName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[p.Attribute.ConfigName];

                var value = Convert.ChangeType(appSettingName, p.Property.PropertyType);

                p.Property.SetValue(AppSettings, value);

                // todo: I want to set this propety now as read-only so they can't change it but not sure how
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is where you probably want to use `Emit` and proxy it out. You can't modify metadata at runtime...

Comment: Never even heard of Emit but it seems like a whole new world. I'll dig deeper.

Comment: Any reason for the down vote? What did I do wrong? It's nice to know for future reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things, one C# does not allow generic attribute classes. So that will not work.

Second, You cannot change the property to read only at run-time. Reflection is for inspecting the metadata of the types loaded, not changing the metadata.

You could back the properties yourself, but that is a bigger endeavor.

Comment: Sorry I should have been more clear, that's not the attribute class, it's the actual "library" class to get strongly typed appSettings in app.config. The attribute class is separate than this but this does all the work of reading the config file and determining  what property to get in the generic type the user passed in based on the properties that are decorated with my attribute. Kind of a bummer you cant change to read-only at run-time. What do you mean back the properties yourself? Also there are ReadOnly attributes in the Component class, does that not change said property to read only?

Comment: To mark a property as read only at runtime code generation can be used `Reflection.Emit` or `Mono.Cecil`. But I don't see any issues with private set accessor of property. Why do you need exactly readonly modificator? Do you want to avoid that anybody set a property via reflection? But I think it's ok, if anybody try it so it is indeed required for him

Comment: @Serg046 I guess in generally I was thinking since app.config is (for the most part) meant to be read-only that these properties should also be read-only. It's not the end of times if they aren't but was just trying to be more standard in the meaning of the app.config idea.

Comment: Private set accessor does not allow to change the value from the external context. So it is read-only, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, for that property but that isn't the class the users make, it's my library class the user uses. The class the user makes that is the mapping to the appSettings they could manually make each field read-only but I was just trying to apply a rule and not make them do it themselves. So they call:

var config = new StrongConfiguration<TestConfig>();

Console.WriteLine(config.AppSettings.ARCPurgeDays)

Where TestConfig is their class that mimics the appSetting section of app.config